# Running a Python file from a ROS Launch file : Cant Find it

Tags: ros, python, roslauch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I have the following Launch file, when I run the launch file it errors saying it cant find the Python file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <node name="brickpi.py" pkg="brickpi" type="brickpi.py" output="screen">
  <node pkg="xv_11_laser_driver" type="neato_laser_publisher" name="xv_11_node">
    <!--<param name="port" value="/dev/tty.usbserial-A9UXLBBR"/>-->
    <param name="port" value="/dev/tty.ACM0"/>
    <param name="firmware_version" value="2"/>
    <param name="frame_id" value="laser"/>
  </node>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_frame_2_laser" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_frame /laser 100"/>
  <include file="default_mapping.launch"/>
  <include file="$(find hector_geotiff)/launch/geotiff_mapper.launch"/>
</launch>
```

The file is in the same directory as the launch file, I have also copied it in to

- /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/brickpi/brickpi.py
- /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/brickpi/src/brickpi.py
- /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/brickpi.py
- /home/pi/catkin_ws/build/brickpi/brickpi.py

error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [brickpi/brickpi.py]: brickpi
ROS path
 [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros ROS path
 [1]=/home/pi/catkin_ws/src ROS path
 [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share ROS path
 [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

**Update**
I have done chmod +x to the file but I must point out I have not made a package.xml, CMakeText or anything, I can run the file on its own via python and all works so maybe my issue is for a **Launch file to use it, I must make a Package?**

All code can be found here
https://github.com/burf2000/ROS_Robot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252515/running-a-python-file-from-a-ros-launch-file-:-cant-find-it/) by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2017-01-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2017-01-20**:
Did you make the Python file executable?

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2017-01-20**:
In your CMakeLists.txt do you have you Python program listed in the `catkin_install_python` section?

I have a working example here: https://gitlab.com/bradanlane/locoro

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-21**:
@burf2000: I think you'll only get (well intended) guesses from other board members, unless we can get access to (a minimal working example of) your code. In principle, this should all work, but there is probably a minor thing missing or not setup correctly which causes problems.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-21**:
@suforeman: that is good advice, but installing artefacts is not needed when working with the `devel` space (as `rosrun` et al. will typically resolve Python packages to the `src` space).

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2017-01-21**:
Thanks @gvdhoorn, I'm still learning. My example still my shed some light. At least it's working for me. I also recall a situation similar to the OP that happened early on in my project. I had forgotten to `source devel/setup.bash`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-21**:
Yes, I was thinking something like that may have happened here (as it should just be enough to `chmod +x` a Python script to `rosrun` it, as long as it's in a ROS pkg), but the OP claim(s)(ed) that he already did that.

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-21**:
I have not chmod +x the file, all I have done is dumped the file in a new directory called brickpi?  Do I need to make a cmaketxt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- I solved this by creating a package :) called burf_robot
- Then I copied the script in to a directory called scripts within the package and did chmod +x
- I then changed the package name in the launch file to the new burf_robot package name
- I then ran catkin_make

---

Originally posted by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) with karma: 202 on 2017-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-22**:
Please don't accept answers when they're not really the answer.

The real solution was to create a package (called `brickpi`) and put the Python script in that.

Seeing as your launch file had `pkg="brickpi"` in it, we all assumed you had already done that. A MWE would have immediately ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-22**:
.. let us know you hadn't.

> my issue is for a Launch file to use it, I must make a Package?

so yes, ROS is package based, and anything you want to `rosrun` **must** be part of a package.

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-22**:
Sorry about that, yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you have to put the brickpi.py in the brickpi folder

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2017-01-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-20**:
I have put it in the brickpi folder?  /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/brickpi/brickpi.py and /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/brickpi/src/brickpi.py

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2017-01-20**:
After creating the ws and the brickpi packet. Did you run catkin_make in your ws folder

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2017-01-20**:
Could you put the PY file in catkin_ws/SRC/brickpi/scripts/